# How we can create a New-ADGroup with -OtherAttributes using powershell command?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

`New-ADGroup -Name 'mygroup1' -GroupScope 0 -OtherAttributes '@{'AttributeLDAPDisplayName'=value}'`

I have tried using above command in powershell but returns following exception :

````
At line:1 char:45
+  New-ADGroup -Name 'mygroup1' -GroupScope 0 -OtherAttributes -Replace ...
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup```
````

Comment: `-OtherAttributes` expects a hash table as argument: Example `-OtherAttributes @{'AttributeLDAPDisplayName'=value}`. Just remove the quotes.

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon tried this `New-ADGroup -Name 'mygroup1' -GroupScope 0 -OtherAttributes @{'AttributeLDAPDisplayName'=value}` but getting this error now instead `value : The term 'value' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` not sure what it means

Answer (score 1):

***As suggested by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) posting it as
answer to help other community members.***

If you use quotes in arguments, it will be treated as **String.** This is not valid for **`-OtherAttributes`** as the type of it is **hashtable**.

So, remove the quotes and include your values to the attribute by replacing `value`.

For suppose, if you are trying to create an Active Directory group based on **Email address** your cmdlet should be something like this:

```
$groupEmail = "user1@gmail.com","user2@gmail.com"
New-ADGroup -Name 'mygroup1' -GroupScope 0 -OtherAttributes @{'mail'=$groupEmail} -Path "CN=Users,OU=Your_OU_Name,DC=Com"
```

If you are trying to create AD group based on **displayName**, please check below cmdlet

(**NOTE**: You can also give the values directly like this):

```
 New-ADGroup -Name 'mygroup1' -GroupScope 0 -OtherAttributes @{'displayName'="Sri","Devi"} -Path "CN=Users,OU=Your_OU_Name,DC=Com"
```

Make sure whether you are giving correct path or not.

Please check the below references if they are helpful.

**References:**

https://ss64.com/ps/new-adgroup.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-adgroup?view=windowsserver2022-ps#parameters